# Как скрыть блок jquery?

Tags: jquery

Как скрыть блок div, если пользователь заходит на пределы его курсором?
Изначально мой блок div отображается по наведению на элемент span, после при вывода курсора  из области с *id="NotificationList"* - нужно скрыть родительский блок *.extendWrapper ()*

```
<span>show</span>
<div class="extendWrapper">
<div id="NotificationList"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: мне кажется ответ хороший, автору вопроса можно его принять

Comment: можно использовать $(el).toggle()

Answer (score 3):

Привет! При помощи jQuery элементы можно скрывать, к примеру, функцией [.hide()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B8c%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Но в таком варианте происходит запись стилей непосредственно в тег элемента.
Я пользуюсь вспомогательным CSS-классом .hidden, для того, чтобы избежать этого.

Пример:

```
$('span').mouseover(function () {
  $('.extendWrapper').removeClass('hidden');
});

$('#NotificationList').mouseout(function () {
  $('.extendWrapper').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Пример на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/tVUh9/4/)

Используй [карту функций](http://jquery.page2page.ru/tags/ifr.html), для более уверенной работы с jQuery. ;-)

Comment: > Но в таком варианте происходит запись стилей непосредственно в тег элемента.

Почему это плохо?

Comment: Засирает разметку, браузер вряд ли кэширует, трудно осуществить одни и те же модификации из разных мест (разных скриптов, или, что более вероятно, при генерации на стороне сервера), сложно отдебажить место появления той или иной модификации на странице.

Хотя анимации, понятное дело, без этого никак не могут.

Comment: > браузер вряд ли кэширует

Не кэширует, кэшируется HTTP, а не HTML. Не вижу проблемы.

> трудно осуществить одни и те же модификации из разных мест

В чём конкретно сложность?

> сложно отдебажить место появления той или иной модификации на странице

Это да, но ведь тут мы код видим, а не HTML.

Всё-таки думаю использовать jquery hide, show правильнее, хотя бы потому что у них веса больше и пишутся короче.

Comment: вариант вполне подходит, но проблема в том, что в самом блоке .extendWrapper есть другие блоки, и соответственно при попадании курсора в их область - блок скрывается. Блок extendWrapper должен скрываться только при выходе за его приделы...Какие есть варианты?

Comment: @IOleg Так раньше вы писали не так:
> при вывода курсора из области с id="NotificationList" - нужно скрыть родительский блок .extendWrapper

Сейчас присутствуют два разных условия. Второе:

> Блок extendWrapper должен скрываться только при выходе за его приделы...

Какое верное?

Сейчас решение по первому условию.

Comment: @IOleg если хотите запускать событие при выходе курсора из области элемента .extendWrapper, установите обработчик события ему. Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/tVUh9/3/